# Reorder array according to reference array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const ids = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"];

const items = [
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."}
];
```

As you can see, ordering is different and items with ids `second` and `sixth` are missing.

- Items in `items` has to be in same order than in `ids`
- Have to have `null` instead of missing items (`second` and `sixth`)

---

Final result looks like this:

```js
const items = [
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  null, // <-- important
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  null  // <-- important
];
```

---

This is a performance critical function and I need it to perform as good as possible.

**Is there anything I can do?** Those counts in performance stats below are all possible cases.

---

#### My function:

```js
console.time('generate');
const arrays = generateArrays(100); // num of items, check perf stats below snippet

console.time('reorder');
reOrder(arrays.ids, arrays.items);


// THIS function is the purpose of this question
function reOrder(ids, items) {
  let result = [];

  ids.forEach((id, i) => {
    const match = items.find((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });

    // Missing, insert null instead
    if (match === undefined) {
       return result[i] = null;
    }
    // Has match, insert to proper index
    return result[i] = match;
  });

  console.timeEnd('reorder');
  console.log('final result:', result);
}


// Generate huge random arrays ([ids], [items])
// * Random items are missing 
// * Items are randomly shuffled
function generateArrays(count) {
  let ids = [];
  let items = [];
  let itemsIndex = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const randomID = Math.random().toString(36).substr(7);
    // Ids have beautiful full array without shenanigans
    ids[i] = randomID;

    // Randomly add items (a.k.a random items are missing)
    if (Math.random() < 0.7) {
      items[itemsIndex] = {
        id: randomID,
        idIndex: i, // to check if final result is correct
        itemIndex: itemsIndex, // to check if shuffled properly
        value: Math.random().toString(36).substr(7)
      };

      itemsIndex++;
    }
  }
  
  shuffleArray(items);
  
  //console.log('generated ids:', ids);
  //console.log('generated items:', items);
  console.timeEnd('generate');

  return {ids: ids, items: items};
}


// Shuffle items in array
function shuffleArray(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
```

```
// Performance stats with my okay PC
--------------------------------------
       Count     |       Time
--------------------------------------
       100             0.3 - 1ms
       500              5 - 10ms
        1K             10 - 25ms

// WARNING, gets messy for weak rigs!

        5K            around 300ms
       10K              1 - 1.5s
```

Comment: Is there always a one to one or one to none match between the order array and the sortable array objects?  Or can one item in the order array match 0 to many in the sortable array? Can the sortable array have ids that are not in the order array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed you could just use the poor man's javascript inbuilt map option. An object's property name can be looked up very quickly making all objects a Map. Map the sortable items then add them to the array in the sort order. Saves you having to call indexOf, or find. Thought a search is still done it will be much quicker than the array methods.

```
const ids = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"];

const items = [
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."}
];
const itemsSort = {};
items.forEach(item => itemsSort[item.id] = item);
items.length = 0;
ids.forEach(id=>items.push(itemsSort[id]));
```

Or use the Map object to do the same. Not sure if the speed matches the above, you will have to try it.

```
// from first snippets data set
const map = new Map();
items.forEach(item => map.set(item.id,item));
items.length = 0;
ids.forEach(id=>items.push(map.get(id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `map()` and create new array.

```js
const ids = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"];

const items = [
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."}
];

var result = ids.map(function(e) {
  var obj = items.find(a => a.id == e);
  return obj ? obj : null
})

console.log(result)
```

You could also create hash table and use it for sorting instead of `find`.

```js
const ids = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"];

const items = [
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."}
];

var hash = items.reduce((r, e) => (r[e.id] = e, r), {})
var result = ids.map(e => hash[e] ? hash[e] : null)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
let result = Array(ids.length).fill(null);
items.forEach((item) => result[ids.indexOf(item.id)] = item);
```

for gerating a new array with the wanted length and `null` value and assign the actual item to the wanted slot.

```js
console.time('generate');
const arrays = generateArrays(100); // num of items, check perf stats below snippet

console.time('reorder');
reOrder(arrays.ids, arrays.items);

function reOrder(ids, items) {
    let result = Array(ids.length).fill(null);
    items.forEach((item) => result[ids.indexOf(item.id)] = item);
    console.timeEnd('reorder');
    console.log('final result:', result);
}


// Generate huge random arrays ([ids], [items])
// * Random items are missing 
// * Items are randomly shuffled
function generateArrays(count) {
    let ids = [];
    let items = [];
    let itemsIndex = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const randomID = Math.random().toString(36).substr(7);
        // Ids have beautiful full array without shenanigans
        ids[i] = randomID;

        // Randomly add items (a.k.a random items are missing)
        if (Math.random() < 0.7) {
            items[itemsIndex] = {
                id: randomID,
                idIndex: i, // to check if final result is correct
                itemIndex: itemsIndex, // to check if shuffled properly
                value: Math.random().toString(36).substr(7)
            };
            itemsIndex++;
        }
    }
  
    shuffleArray(items);
  
    console.timeEnd('generate');
    return {ids: ids, items: items};
}


// Shuffle items in array
function shuffleArray(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For speed, if you are able to change `ids`, I would make it an object instead of an array. That way you can use it as a quick lookup table for the proper index instead of having to constantly loop over an array with `Array.prototype.findIndex`.

```js
const ids = {
  "first": 0,
  "second": 1,
  "third": 2,
  "fourth": 3,
  "fifth": 4,
  "sixth": 5
};

const items = [
  {id: "third", value: ".."},
  {id: "fifth", value: ".."},
  {id: "first", value: ".."},
  {id: "fourth", value: ".."}
];

// create an array of nulls that has as many
// entries as there are items in ids
let sorted = [];
sorted.length = Object.keys(ids).length;
sorted.fill(null);

// loop over the items we have and insert them
// into the proper slots in the array of nulls
items.forEach((item) => {
  let index = ids[item.id];
  sorted[index] = item;
});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sorted, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

In addition looping over `items` instead of `ids` should be faster since if you only need to iterate over what is actually there instead of for each item that should be there.